# How do I get the data from selected rows in PostgreSQL from Flutter app when I'm passing it through Cloud Function (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I use Cloud Function to fetch rows from a PostgeSQL server in the cloud and return the query result to Flutter app.

Here is the code in the Cloud Function (Node.js):

```
// Defining pgPool
const pg = require('pg');
var pgPool;

// Open connection to Postgres
if (pgPool == null) {
  pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig);
}

exports.getUser = functions
  .runWith({ memory: "256MB", timeoutSeconds: 10 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
   
   const queryString = `select * from users where uid=${data[uid]}`;

   return await pgPool.query(queryString);
});
```

This is how I call the function in my Flutter app,

```
final HttpsCallable getUser = CloudFunctions.instance
   .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'getUser');

final response = await getUser.call({uid: uid});

// Print the result
print('Got data: ${response.data}');
```

I got the data alright but the data looks like this:

```
flutter: Got data: {fields: [{format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 1, dataTypeModifier: 24, tableID: 16442, name: pid, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 2, dataTypeModifier: 32, tableID: 16442, name: uid, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 2, dataTypeModifier: 54, tableID: 16416, name: name, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 4, dataTypeModifier: 10, tableID: 16442, name: cid, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 3, dataTypeModifier: 24, tableID: 16442, name: aid, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: -1, columnID: 6, dataTypeModifier: 354, tableID: 16442, name: msg, dataTypeID: 1043}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: 8, columnID: 5, dataTypeModifier: -1, tableID: 16442, name: crd, dataTypeID: 1114}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: 8, columnID: 7, dataTypeModifier: -1, tableID: 16442, name: upd, dataTypeID: 1114}, {format: text, dataTypeSize: 4, columnID: 8, dataTypeModifier: -1, t<…>
```

So instead of the actual data, I actually got a description of each column.

The question is how do I get the actual rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line of code `return await pgPool.query(queryString);`, you're returning the entire [response object](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries), whereas you just need the rows, so do something like this:

```js
const result = await pgPool.query(queryString)
return result.rows
```

You can also opt for an ORM like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) or TypeOrm (if you use Typescript) that will make DB queries easier, validate data, etc.

About JSON response, Cloud Functions should convert in JSON the returned JS object/array, instead if you decide to use Express on top of Cloud Functions, just use Express `res.json(result.rows)`

Comment: Oh why someone down vote on the question? Let me know if there is anything unclear so I can fix it. Thanks